# Python communicate and subprocess.popen hung on reading stdin, when stdin is default None

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, python-2.4

I have a python daemon process. This daemon process spawns a thread to cater to a call to my daemon everytime a command is invoked.
From within the thread, I use Python subprocess popen to execute such shell commands like

```
   def __executeCommand(self, cmd):
            try:
                    self.__assertEmptyCommand(cmd)
                    logger.debug('Executing command : '+str(cmd))
                    #kept for use after analysis
                    #cmd = cmd.split(' ')
                    #proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
                    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                    (output, error) = proc.communicate()
                    returnCode = proc.returncode
                    logger.debug('Command execution finished: Cmd:'+ str(cmd) + "\nReturn code:" \
                            + str(returnCode) + "\nOutput:" + str(output) + "\nError:" + str(error))
                    if output is '':
                            output = []
                    returnOutput = output
                    if(output != [] and output[-1] == '\n'):
                            returnOutput = output[:-1]
                    return (returnCode, str(returnOutput), str(error))
```

During the execution of some commands, proc.communicate() never returns.
When I checked the strace of the parent daemon under which thread was executed
following was the strace output

```
### Looking at strace for PID -> 14879 -> Main Daemon process ###

[root@mymach ~]# strace -p 14879
Process 14879 attached - interrupt to quit
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 122000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {2, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
```

Looking at the strace of the child PID that was executing a shell under popen.

```
### Looking at strace for PID -> 24294  -> Child Process process ###
[root@mymach ~]# strace -p 24294
Process 24294 attached - interrupt to quit
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>) = 0
nanosleep({0, 2000001}, NULL)           = 0
nanosleep({0, 2000001}, NULL)           = 0
nanosleep({0, 2000001}, NULL)           = 0
nanosleep({0, 2000001}, NULL)           = 0
nanosleep({0, 2000001}, NULL)           = 0
nanosleep({0, 2000001}, NULL)           = 0
```

I attached gdb to running daemon process and I saw the following stack trace of the thread that was executing the popen code

```
### attaching GDB to main Daemon Process ###

[root@mymach ~]# gdb attach 14879
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5.HYDRA)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
--snip--
(gdb) info thread
  11 Thread 0x406c4940 (LWP 15072)  0x00000035ee00e291 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  10 Thread 0x410c5940 (LWP 15073)  0x00000035ee00b1c0 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  9 Thread 0x41ac6940 (LWP 15075)  0x00000035ee00b1c0 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  8 Thread 0x424c7940 (LWP 15078)  0x00000035ee00e291 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  7 Thread 0x42ec8940 (LWP 15081)  0x00000035ee00b1c0 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  6 Thread 0x438c9940 (LWP 15084)  0x00000035ee00cd91 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  5 Thread 0x442ca940 (LWP 15085)  0x00000035ed4cc3f2 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  4 Thread 0x44ccb940 (LWP 15088)  0x00000035ee00dc0b in accept () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  3 Thread 0x49cd3940 (LWP 24090)  0x00000035ee00cd91 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  2 Thread 0x47ed0940 (LWP 24281)  0x00000035ee00d9eb in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0 -----------------> Thread common for PID -> 24294 
* 1 Thread 0x2b34ca2d7610 (LWP 14879)  0x00000035ed4cc3f2 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0x47ed0940 (LWP 24281))]#0  0x00000035ee00d9eb in read ()
   from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000035ee00d9eb in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000035ee8bfc41 in read (self=<value optimized out>, args=<value optimized out>)
   from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
--snip--
#20 0x00000035ee895ad8 in call_function (f=0x2c00013339e0) at Python/ceval.c:3656
#21 PyEval_EvalFrame (f=0x2c00013339e0) at Python/ceval.c:2163
#22 0x00000035ee895c8b in call_function (f=0x2c0002bb9a20) at Python/ceval.c:3645
#23 PyEval_EvalFrame (f=0x2c0002bb9a20) at Python/ceval.c:2163
#24 0x00000035ee895c8b in call_function (f=0x2c0002136020) at Python/ceval.c:3645
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
```

Attaching GDB to child process that was so created the back trace is as follows

```
[root@mymach ~]# gdb attach 24294
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5.HYDRA)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
--snip--
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000035ee00e291 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00002b34ca068258 in SpinLock::SlowLock (this=0x2b34ca298440)
    at src/allocator/base/spinlock.cc:104
#2  0x00002b34ca061526 in Lock (this=0x2b34ca298440, start=0x47ecd330, end=0x47ecd328,
    N=<value optimized out>) at src/allocator/base/spinlock.h:90
#3  tcmalloc::CentralFreeList::RemoveRange (this=0x2b34ca298440, start=0x47ecd330, end=0x47ecd328,
    N=<value optimized out>) at src/allocator/central_freelist.cc:219
#4  0x00002b34ca059ffe in tcmalloc::ThreadCache<false>::FetchFromCentralCache (
    this=0x2c00000305c0, cl=<value optimized out>, byte_size=48)
    at src/allocator/thread_cache.cc:159
#5  0x00002b34ca05e420 in Allocate (this=0x2c0000030580, size=<value optimized out>)
    at src/allocator/thread_cache.h:331
#6  allocateWithSizeUpdate (this=0x2c0000030580, size=<value optimized out>)
    at src/allocator/tcmalloc_heap.h:110
#7  allocate (this=0x2c0000030580, size=<value optimized out>) at src/allocator/stats_heap.h:77
#8  tcmalloc::Heapifier<tcmalloc::StatsHeap<false> >::allocate (this=0x2c0000030580,
    size=<value optimized out>) at src/allocator/heap.h:107
#9  0x00002b34ca0794f2 in unlimited_cpp_alloc (old_ptr=0x0, new_size=<value optimized out>)
    at src/allocator/tcmalloc.cc:850
--snip--
```

I am not sure why is the child process waiting for a SpinLock on FD 0 (stdin) and also the main daemon waiting for a read() response on FD 0 (stdin).
The above does not come at all times, but comes at certain moments and other moments it is just fine!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because we were using a custom allocator, which was getting blocked because of memory allocation in subprocess.popen.

Question needs to be ignored.